# Why is rspec reporting the time with fractions?

Tags: ruby, rspec

A somewhat lighthearted question:  My rspec tests end with:

```
Finished in 7/5 minutes 0.78322 seconds
```

What exactly does that mean?   It did feel approximately like 1-2 minutes, but why the fraction plus decimal seconds?

Comment: Which version of RSpec are you using?

Comment: 2.10.1  ... in rails environment

Comment: updated to 2.11, still looks funny

Comment: Is this what they call rhetorical question?

Comment: could you push to github a simple app that reproduces this issue?

Comment: I take it no one else sees this?

Comment: I've never seen it. To second @nash, could you push something somewhere that demonstrates the problem? The only thing I could imagine is that something is overriding `RSpec::Core::Formatters::Helpers#format_duration`, but that seems really unlikely.

Comment: What specific version of ruby? What other gems are present? I agree it feels like something is monkey patching a core class.

Comment: I have a ton of gems in this project... it's going to take a while to chase it down.

Comment: Sounds like something monkeypatched something it shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it certainly looks like RSpec (or somebody) is calculating the number of minutes as a [`Rational`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html) instead of a normal `Numeric`. That's the only reason I can imagine you'd see a fractional value.

Comment: Yeah, though it's really weird that there is a decimal seconds in addition to that.